# How to join entites like they are tables in Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

The documentation on how to retrieve joined entites as one object is very sparse, and most Stack Overflow questions on the subject are many years old.

I have a symfony project up and running with a database schema fully mapped in Doctrine. In my controllers I am able to run these two queries one after the other and they work fine.

```
$page = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('PageBundle:SitePages')
    ->findByprodpageid($id);

$matrices = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('PageBundle:SiteMatrices')
    ->findByprodpageid($id);
```

however both of them contain the attribute prodpageid and I would like to join the two entities on this column and receive one object containing all column values from both tables.

I am building this on top of an existing database structure so anything to do with changing the database structure etc is out of the question.

I have added annotations in my entities to specify which columns should be joined, in a ManyToOne relationship. But how do I activate that relation and receive the joined object?

Thanks for any info on the subject.

EDIT: Here are my relationships from the entities

//Entities/SitePages

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ProdPageID", type="smallint")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SiteMatrices")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="prodpageid", referencedColumnName="prodpageid")
 */
private $prodpageid;
```

//Entities/SiteMatrices

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ProdPageID", type="smallint", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SitePages")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="prodpageid", referencedColumnName="prodpageid")
 *
 */
private $prodpageid;
```

Comment: Can you c&p the many to many definition on both sides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are saying that a `Page` has many `Matrices`. I will make some changes by your permission in mapping annotations:

```
/**
 * Entities/SitePages
 *
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ProdPageID", type="smallint")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SiteMatrices")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="prodpageid", referencedColumnName="prodpageid")
 */
private $matrices;

/**
* @return ArrayCollection
*/
public function getMatrices(){
   return $this->matrices;
}

/**
* @param Entities/SiteMatrices[]
* @return $this
*/
public function setMatrices($matrices){
    $this->matrices = $matrices;
    return $this;
}
```

and

```
/**
 * Entities/SiteMatrices
 *
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ProdPageID", type="smallint", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SitePages")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="prodpageid", referencedColumnName="prodpageid")
 *
 */
private $page;

/**
* @return Entities/SitePages
*/
public function getPage(){
   return $this->page;
}

/**
* @param Entities/SitePages
* @return $this
*/
public function setPage($page){
    $this->page = $page;
    return $this;
}
```

Now if you query the Pages with this DQL:

```
$pages = $this->getDoctrine()
   ->getRepository('PageBundle:SitePages')
   ->findByprodpageid($id);
```

Then you could get each page's matrices simply by traversing on matrices association:

```
foreach($pages as $page){
    $matrices = $page->getMatrices(); // will give you an ArrayCollection of all matrices objects joined by prodpageid to this page.
}
```

Hope I did not get you wrong and it helps.

Comment: Thankyou for pointing me in the right direction. I didnt get from the documentation that another variable was needed in the entity to represent the foreign entity and the mapping was done there. However implementing your code has just led me into lots of errors with various options for the doctrine mappings. Circular References, unrecognised column id values, and after picking through those to get to a working state, I call the function to getMatrices on a page object and the result contains an entire dump of the doctrine object. Thanks for the nudge on the concept,but implementation is wrong.

Comment: @Asq Sorry to hear about the errors, but we are using this implementation in our production.
In Doctrine when we have an association like the `page` in `matrices`, we will not write the `page_id`, we will define a property with the name of association we want like in our case `page` and then in mapping annotations we will point to `page_id` as the foreign key used in this association.

Comment: @Asq I think these errors `Circular References, unrecognised column id` relate to this part: `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="prodpageid", referencedColumnName="prodpageid")`, because typically we write it as :
`@ORM\JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="id")` and that `id` is pointing to `Page` entity primary key field.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on the idea Mohammed, I will play with this idea more today and get back to you on my success

Comment: Hi Mohammed, thanks to your answer and comments I have managed to find my way. Im not sure what was wrong, but it must have been a light formatting error. when I pull my page entity it now contains an array named 'matrices' containing all associated matrix objects which is what I was after.
The official documentation on this subject is very confusing and the mappings have to be perfect to work. I would advise anyone in the same boat to persevere, and use Mohammed example above as a starting point. Just make sure all your column names in the mapping are correct etc as they are case sensitive.

Comment: As an extra bit of help anyone having circular reference issues as a result of mapping entites such as these take a look here for the answer - http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-circular-references
Remember when calling your mapped entities directly through getters doctrine will give you a PersistentCollection object rather than an array.

Comment: @Asq wow, I am happy that It could help. It was an interesting article.